# attr('selected','selected') not work in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#sellist option').each(function(index) {
    var str ='4/5/8';
    var substr = str.split('/');
    if (substr[0] == $(this).attr('value')) {
        $(this).attr('selected','selected');
        alert('hi'); ///For check
    }
});
```

Every thing works fine and `alert` is fired. I havent any error in console. But `#sellist option` is not selected which I want. What is my problem. Thanks.

Comment: did you forget to quote 4/5/8?

Comment: @tanyehzheng nop its a typing mistake.Any way thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine. It is just selecting the first element of your array, `4` because you are not looping through the array, you just use `substr[0]` to get the first value.

To see that it works I changed the initial value to `7`:

```
$('#sellist option').each(function(index) {
    var str = "7/5/8";
    var substr = str.split('/');

    if (substr[0] == $(this).val()) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        alert($(this).val()); ///For check
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle to show it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tD9Tv/1/)

**OP Clarified he want to loop around array**

To loop through your array and select each value in the multiple select, use this:

```
$('#sellist option').each(function(index) {
    var str = "4/5/8";
    var substr = str.split('/');

    for (var i = 0; i < substr.length; i++) {
        if (substr[i] == $(this).val()) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }
});
```

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tD9Tv/3/)

Comment: i dont understand `array to select multiple values` bcz code select only single value.I use `<select id="sellist"  multiple="multiple">`.Plz show a correct direction.Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer to loop through the array and select each value.

Answer (score 21):

Replace attr by prop.

```
$('#element').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: To clarify: selected, checked etc. are properties, as mentioned in the .prop() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: This did it for me. I wonder why, especially after changing the selected option multiple times, .attr() stops working but this works

Comment: Same thing.  I ran into an issue where attr() only worked the first time where as prop() worked on every instance.

Comment: er, I mean... jQuery is dead! who still uses that stuff? not me!

Comment: In my case this was  the solution, on firs time I'm load the page the "$(this).attr('selected','selected')" not work, after reload a select start to working,

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr('selected','selected');
```

should be replaced by:

```
$(this).attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, this does work in jQuery, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/Du6Ra/) to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one option to be selected, for example, you want the option with value `4` to be selected, just do `$('#sellist').val('4');`

Comment: i have multipal value to select any idea.Thanks. :(

Comment: The `.val()` works with the `select`. I don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this:

```
var str ='4/5/8';
$.each(str.split('/'), function(i, val) {
    $('#sellist option').filter('[value="' + val + '"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/KPGnx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$('#sellist').val($(this).attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr('selected', true);` should do the trick for ya.